# Android Studio Gradle task stuck

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I've installed android studio. It's Gradle process hasn't  finish after 2 hours. What should I do for ending this process?

[image]

Comment: Did you try clicking the red X next to the progressbar?

Comment: I end the progress. now tells Error:Could not run build action using Gradle installation 'C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\gradle\gradle-2.10'.

Comment: That's all it says? Nothing more than that? I would suggest you open a command prompt and run Gradle build, as long as you're comfortable with that

Comment: Is it the first time you run android studio? It will take a long time to install gradle. But you can install it manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is with your internet connection because of which gradle is failing to resolve the dependencies.

1. make sure you are connected.
2. make sure if you are behind proxy server the proxy settings are entered correctly in your `gradle.properties` file

Here is how you do it: (change the ip and ports to that of your proxy server

```
#systemProp.https.nonProxyHosts=localhost
#systemProp.httpp.nonProxyHosts=localhost
#systemProp.https.proxyPort=8080
#systemProp.http.proxyHost=10.11.12.13
#systemProp.https.proxyHost=10.11.12.13
#systemProp.http.proxyPort=8080
```